# Something in the cordova / angular / ionic stack steals my focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, accessibility

In order to provide Accessibility i need to to focus elements when entering screens in my Cordova app. With some tricks i managed to set the focus on an element, but the element looses the focus in an instant (verified by listening for the "blur" event) and the loss happens before Apples VoiceOver, Androids Talkback kicks in or the User can take any actions.

I already tried wrapping the setting of the focus inside the $timeout to force it to happen after everything is rendered but that did not help at all. It occurs to me that something in Cordova, angular 1 or ionic does some nasty focus magic on its own interfering with m code.

Has anybody experienced something smiliar and found a workaround for that?

Comment: What element is taking the focus? `document.addEventListener('focus', function(e) { console.log(e.target) }, true)`

Comment: The body element gets the focus which also includes the ng-app attribute: 

`<body ng-app="constructionkit" class="grade-a platform-webview platform-cordova platform-android platform-android6 platform-android6_0 platform-ready statusbar-translucent topbar-default modal-open" tabindex="-1"> 
<!-- Lots of stuff --> 
</body>`

If tried both: removing and setting the tabindex="-1" attribute on body. Does not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

I used following directive for Cordova-Ionic:

```
app.directive('focusableInput', function($timeout,$log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            focusState: "=",
            onGo: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            var moveCursorToEnd = function(el) {
                if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
                    el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
                } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
                    el.focus();
//                    var range = el.createTextRange();
//                    range.collapse(false);
//                    range.select();
                }
            }

            scope.$watch("focusState", function(state) {
                $log.debug("focusableInput - focus state change: " + state,element);
                if (state) {
                    //cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
                    $log.debug("focusableInput - do focus!!!",element);
                    $timeout(function() {
                        element[0].focus();
                        moveCursorToEnd(element[0]);
                    }, 300);

                    //element[0].focus();
                } else {
                    element[0].blur();
                }
            });

            element.on("keydown", function(event) {
                console.log("pressed: " + event.which, event);
                //$log.debug(attr);

                if (event.which == 13) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        scope.onGo();
                    });
                }
            });



            scope.$watch(
                    function() {
                        return ngModel.$modelValue;
                    },
                    function(newValue) {
                        $log.debug("focus input model changed: ", newValue);

                        if (newValue) {
                            var endChar = newValue[newValue.length - 1];
                            $log.debug("endChar",endChar);

                            if (endChar == " " || endChar == ",") {
                                $timeout(function() {
                                    scope.addItem();
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    };
});
```

And usage:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" 
               class="login-custom-input"
               focusable-input 
               focus-state="textAreaFocusState"
               ng-model="meeterAccount.email"
               ng-focus="onSignUpLoginEmailFocus()"
               ng-blur="onSignUpLoginEmailFocusLost()"
               >
```

`focusable-input` directive uses `focus-state` attribute

---

Hope it will help you.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me. First of all: i don't want to focus only imput field but also headings inside ionics modal view for instance. However after making your suggestion a little more general did not help for me. It does something but still the focus ends up beeing on the body.

(Verified by bodyel.addEventListener('focus', function (el) {
console.log.('new focus'.document.activeElement)}